# mysqli_query() sempre retorna true mesmo quando não altera registro update

Tags: php

Estou executando a query no banco de dados:

`UPDATE store SET status = '0' WHERE id ='325'`

E sempre retorna `true` mesmo se o valor não é atualizado, e quanto uso a função `mysqli_num_rows($link)` da erro de parâmetro `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`,

A query é formada assim:

`Update('store', array('status' => 0), "id ={$arr['store]['id']}'");`

Os parametros são: `tabela`, `array campos=>valor` e `cláusula where`

Comment: A função retorna `true` pois a *query* foi aplicada com sucesso, independente de ter feito ou não as alterações. Utilize `mysqli_affected_rows` para verificar se algum registro foi modificado.

Comment: Retorna `true` pq não deu nenhum erro, se o banco estiver com o autocommit desligado não vai gravar. Para saber quantas linhas foram modificados use `mysqli_affected_rows($link)`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr lol eu achei que já tinha testado com `mysqli_affected_rows`, vlw!